# Stored procedures in Entity Framework and SaveChanges

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure which inserts a new record in table `Pages`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.msp_CreatePage  
(
@NamespaceID int,
@Title varchar(255),
@Redirect bit,
@New bit,
@LatestPageID int
)

AS
INSERT INTO Pages (NamespaceID, Title, Redirect, New, LatestPageID)
VALUES (@NamespaceID, @Title, @Redirect, @New, @LatestPageID);
RETURN
```

From my class method I was calling it using:

```
Entity.msp_CreatePage(namespaceID, title, redirect, new, latestpageid);
Entity.SaveChanges();
```

However, this didn't do any insertion in the database. I used the `AddObject` method to add directly a new object instead, but I wish to know what the problem may be?

Comment: Entity.SaveChanges();  is not needed.

Comment: Does this apply to all other commands like update and delete?

Comment: No, Only stored procedures and functions are executed directly in sql. there is no need to call SaveChanges unless you are directly working with entity objects

Comment: Are you in a transaction that isn't committed? Either within the scope of TransactionScope that doesn't have Save called on it, or a transaction one explicitly started with context.Connection.BeginTransaction?